# how to display web page in inside email body using external url

Tags: php, html, email, iframe, file-get-contents

I need to display web page in email (not to send html of page in email) like iframe,  (not working in email).

If I used file_get_contents not working properly  (showing css issues) (both are not wokring in email).

From my research / knowledge , I didn't found any possible ways, but is there any hack, that might possible to make this happen.

Please help me on this.

Comment: Email, especially HTML is a rather complex task. Worrying about delivery rates, open rates and the general call to action need to be much more aggressive than in a web-page. I would suggest starting with a boilerplate email framework, such as http://emailframe.work/ and replicating the look and feel of the webpage. Don't add everything and tease the content for your CTR. Analytics in a webpage is vastly better than an email.

Comment: I do also recall that there was a function inside Safari that allowed send webpage as email. Not sure if it still exists and the first and last time I used it (most likely 10 years ago) my domain was blacklisted from huge bounce rates. Today I would guess the email would be very hard to pass the Spam Filters.

Comment: @Darren That's a good reference link. I never saw it before.

Answer (score 2):

Iframes / JavaScript are often blocked by email clients (as you may have already researched and found out)

One thing that could fake a webpage inside an email is an image with map tag.
The support for map tags in email clients is not perfect, but you can make some of them work with really basic code.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<table><tr><td>
<img src="http://www.emailonacid.com/images/blog_images/Emailology/2017/2017_imagemap/shapes.jpg" usemap="#image-map" width="600">
<map name="image-map">
    <area target="new" alt="Square" title="Rectangle" href="https://www.google.com/#q=rectangle" coords="30,29,306,153" shape="rect">
    <area target="new" alt="Triangle" title="Triangle" href="https://www.google.com/#q=triangle" coords="323,267,572,26,571,267" shape="poly">
</map>
</td></tr></table>
<hr>
<img src="https://www.w3schools.com/tags/planets.gif" width="145" height="126" alt="Planets" usemap="#planetmap">

<map name="planetmap">
  <area shape="rect" coords="0,0,82,126" href="sun.htm" alt="Sun">
  <area shape="circle" coords="90,58,3" href="mercur.htm" alt="Mercury">
  <area shape="circle" coords="124,58,8" href="venus.htm" alt="Venus">
</map>
</body>
</html>
```

I am not entirely sure you can't load a website inside an email, but I am fairly confident that even if you do it won't work properly.

So if this method could save your skin now, try making a ~600px wide screenshot of the website, upload it to https://www.image-map.net/ or any other tool, and start mapping :)